# node JS express framework sendFile("home.html",{context?})

Tags: node.js, express, render, sendfile

I'm reading the Express framework docs, making my basic login/redirect page routes.
The following route accepts the submission:

```
app.post('/',function(req,res){
//console.log("USERNAME: "+req.body.username);
//console.log("PASSWORD: "+req.body.password);
res.redirect('/chat');
});
```

and this:

```
app.get('/chat', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/templates/chat.html');
    //console.log("request");
});
```

takes the user to a new page. 
How do I send context? Should I be using res.render()? Neither function seems to contain an option for data like {username:req.body.username}. How should data be passed between routes?

Comment: What do you mean "send context"?   You can use a server-side session (see express-session) or you can set a cookie and put some data in the cookie if you want to add some state to a given browser's requests.

Comment: For temporal state of only the next request, you can also redirect to a URL containing query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to handle logins with express you'd use something like [passport's local strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local), which attaches a user object to the request object (`req.user`) for you for each route. I don't know that what you're trying will work in a larger context -- you'd need some kind of session-based middleware like [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) at the very least, so you can attach variables per session (I think it gives you `req.session`). By default, express has the capability to store information for one request/response cycle ([`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals)) or for the entire instance of the app (i.e. for all users) ([`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals)).

As far as getting data into views, you would use `res.render` with something like EJS, pug, or another view engine. For example, if in your route, you had something like:

```
route.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('template', { username: 'yourname' })
}
```

you can refer to that in your ejs template like so:

```
<h1>Hello, <%= username %>!</h1>
```

which will get sent back as this:

```
<h1>Hello, yourname!</h1>
```

So, to answer your question:

- You would use `res.render` to get variables & data into your views
- You don't share data across routes by default except app-level data that applies to all users, which can be set on `app.locals`
- You can use authentication middleware like passport and session middleware like express-session to keep track of user information across routes per session.

Hope this helps! Good luck with express!